# using curl to trigger a notification over http e.g. when a long running task has completed?

Tags: linux, http, service, curl

Today I left work with a long running task running in the shell. For the sake of argument let's say I'm using 'wc -l' to count lines in a huge file. I'd like to get a notification when it is done, but I can't rely on email. I want to use curl to trigger an event on some online notification service, which I can then check for from home.

```
wc -l some_huge_file; curl http://some-notification-service.com
```

Are there any notification services out there that I could use with curl? I imagine that issuing a GET request to some resource, sets a flag that the job has completed, send an sms, email or whatever.

Any ideas for what to hit with that curl GET/POST/PUT/WHATEVER request?

Comment: Can you be more specific? First you said that you cant rely on email, after you said "send an sms, email or whatever"

Comment: Marcelo: I realize that could be confusing. What I mean is that I'm not assuming sendmail to be installed/configured on the system where I'm running the task. The system that receives the GET request could have mail, sms etc features for notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just notice that:

- if you want to know your command executed successfully or not, check
  the exit status with `$?`.
- Twitter no longer supports basic authentication. Take a look at
  [Tweepy](http://talkfast.org/2010/05/31/twitter-from-the-command-line-in-python-using-oauth)
  or [Twurl](https://github.com/marcel/twurl).

Comment: I would +1 for both the status and pointing out the problem with basic auth, but I just started using serverfault (rating too low :-)).

Comment: I'll look at Tweepy/Twurl and get back to you with a possible accepted answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be a service?

You can send an [SMS](http://www.janitha.com/archives/90) message via sendmail.

You can use [twitter](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/twittering-command-line)

You can use [Facebook](http://www.stopgeek.com/simultaneously-update-twitter-and-facebook-from-the-command-line.html)

Comment: quanta is right. Trying the twit script gives: Basic authentication is not supported.

Comment: I'm specifically not relying on anything but curl, so sendmail is not an option. I mean service in the broadest sense (anything that accepts a GET request), so twitter would have been good, if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I made this simple bash script as a nagios check, to download a file using curl and verify if the contents MD5 matches a provided value...

You can easily modify it to your needs...

https://github.com/mabitt/mab-nagios-plugins/blob/master/check_urlmd5.sh

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and for sharing code, but I think you misunderstood my question.